# How to implement HAVING clause with AND KEYWORD in MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am making an application where Item will be delivered from one place to another. The database saves the sending location or address (along with the sending latitude and longitude) and the receiving address or location(along with the destination latitude and longitude).

I am making a search application which will receive data like

1. sending_latitude $Flat
2. Sending_longitude $Flon
3. Destination_latitude $Tlat
4. Destination_longitude $Tlon
5. From_date $date
6. Radius $r

Then it will search the item list to find the locations of the points within the specified radius parameter of the given geographic position and having the date matching `from_date`.

### My Query:

```
SELECT *, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_from_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `senddistance`, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_to_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_to_latitude`))
            )
        ) `todistance`
FROM `items` as Item
HAVING (`senddistance` < $rad AND `todistance` < $rad)
ORDER BY `senddistance`
```

It's working fine as anticipated. However, I want to add another conditing `AND from_date = $date` in the Conditions.

So I wrote the query like this:

### Modified Query:

```
SELECT *, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_from_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `senddistance`, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_to_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_to_latitude`))
            )
        ) `todistance`
FROM `items` as Item
WHERE from_date = $date
HAVING (`senddistance` < $rad AND `todistance` < $rad)
ORDER BY `senddistance`
```

It just simply returns empty result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So I think it means that all the rows have `from_date` not equal to `$date`

Comment: It should be as simple as @KaeL says. I believe you misuse `having`. No aggregate function is used. The condition refers to the row itself. `where` should have been used, especially if you want to use an index combining some of the columns in the condition. So, what type is the `from_date` column and what are you comparing the column to? Could it be that `from_date` is of text/varchar type and `$date` goes in the query without quotes?

Comment: My comment is bad and I should feel bad. Bottom line is that you should look into `having`/`where` important differences, but this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `HAVING`with `WHERE`?

- `HAVING`is typically used for filtering after you applied `GROUP BY`
- `WHERE`filters results before grouping

Answer (score 0):

if the condition is for the query you must add where
You don't need the () around the having condition for this case

```
SELECT *, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_from_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `senddistance`, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_to_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_to_latitude`))
            )
        ) `todistance`
FROM `items` as Item
WHERE from_date = $date
HAVING `senddistance` < $rad AND `todistance` < $rad
ORDER BY `senddistance`
```

In the condition  is for filtering the result after group by  then you can add the condition in having clause and  however you don't need ()

```
SELECT *, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_from_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `senddistance`, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_to_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_to_latitude`))
            )
        ) `todistance`
FROM `items` as Item
HAVING  `senddistance` < $rad 
AND `todistance` < $rad
AND from_date = $date
ORDER BY `senddistance`
```

anyway do the fact you are not using aggregation function and you don't have group bu then you don't should use having but only where

```
SELECT *, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_from_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `senddistance`, (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                cos( radians( `sending_to_latitude` ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( `sending_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                ) +
                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                sin(radians(`sending_to_latitude`))
            )
        ) `todistance`
FROM `items` as Item
WHERE from_date = $date
AND `senddistance` < $rad 
AND `todistance` < $rad
ORDER BY `senddistance`
```